# Execution on Add-on of Google Sheets throws PERMISSION_DENIED error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

We published an add-on in the Google Marketplace. It works on Google Sheets.

Its written in Google Apps Script, the fact is when we are on the developer account it works perfectly, but when we install it on another accounts
some functions doesn't work (the ones we assign to images on the sheets), on the project execution we get time 0s and in the cloud logs we get the PERMISSION_DENIED error and we don't know why is this happening.
Since the functions to generate the sheets are working well and are on the same script.

Here we have a video reproducing the error:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ylgjszv6-pEZV3RbRiO_JUapjkL4oSgG/view?usp=sharing

And here is also the JSON of the error in Cloud log explorer

`{ "insertId": "-gn21y0evi7t3", "jsonPayload": { "serviceContext": { "service": "AKfycbxBeGMG3RnIPYv9abPDfLyhqO9Syh1dePOuqq7ACOqVtDM" }, "message": "Se ha producido un error de servidor mientras se leía del almacenamiento. Código de error: PERMISSION_DENIED." }, "resource": { "type": "app_script_function", "labels": { "function_name": "Install", "invocation_type": "menu", "project_id": "door-opener-365907" } }, "timestamp": "2023-02-01T14:19:25.472Z", "severity": "ERROR", "labels": { "script.googleapis.com/process_id": "EAEA1GOxSkmncFik5KARbcKqGQRiSbwbSH8COxiJJX_xwosmdOYeBXgSXaYi8HyBg36qiPWYid4HhIdiFr_8xmq2lzQxP549ELze_97LxQ-hkXMv7ZoVxsR27T23RwLzg7KDOdXLRGGouhQ8ZjJeNtvNTRwsOBIEfbXtSXSj2OMFnrQIID7zxTrXZVqrX3buNMpsgG6CwSDV4UpIIzX99Pe19RtGMA_UmgfrUCbDq-vhF6K2C2CFXx40KU8enuGKBMWZrsXMkY39C65KB6dx6ADpFaepRepwXx6anjztU", "script.googleapis.com/project_key": "MLMTt4IvnipVJ69ylzgTEpqzUywQkXZem", "script.googleapis.com/deployment_id": "AKfycbxBeGMG3RnIPYv9abPDfLyhqO9Syh1dePOuqq7ACOqVtDM" }, "logName": "projects/door-opener-365907/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs", "receiveTimestamp": "2023-02-01T14:19:25.646491972Z" }`

Thanks in advance for your help

We tried changing the visibility of the add-on, also tried to share the spreadsheet where the main code was (This worked but we dont want to do it this way since we already published and verify the add-on).

The expected behaivour is to be able to run the same functions of the code in any spreadsheet that has the add-on installed.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "tried to share the spreadsheet where the main code was", please? What is the script trying to access that gets the permission denied?

Comment: I mean that if we share the sheet with the app script code the functions inserted on the images of the sheet work, but when we install the add-on in another user those functions doesn't work, but the ones that are generated on the menu on the upper bar work. And when we get the permisiion denied its when we try to run the functions added to the new spreadsheets generated by the previous function, located on the same script as the ones that generate the sheets.

Comment: Apps Script code is in its own file, it's not part of the spreadsheet. However, if you are trying to share a Sheet macro (which is not Apps Script) then that's not possible, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/sheets#sheets_macros.
Try using the getting started to create a simple Sheet add-on that works and take it from there: https://script.google.com/corp/home/projects/create?template=spreadsheet.